# Cannot understand error when decoding base 64 encoded graphic

Tags: python, python-3.x

I imported a file `background_image.txt` containing the string reference `background_image` a base 64 encoded graphic. When I compile the program I get the error in the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    background_image = io.StringIO(base64.decode(background_image.background_image))
TypeError: decode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
```

This is line #23

```
background_image = io.StringIO(base64.decode(background_image.background_image)) # line 23
```

This is the reduced verison of my program. This program creates a window using tkinter using the base 64 encoded graphic as the canvas background.

```
# modules
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import io
import base64

# imported files
import background_image 

# variables 
background_image = io.StringIO(base64.decode(background_image.background_image)) # line 23

# window creation
root = Tk()

# canvas creation
canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bd=-2) 
canvas.pack()

# canvas attributes 
background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=background_image)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=background, anchor=NW)
text = canvas.create_text(125, 75, anchor=CENTER)

# end
root.after(0, display)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html), base64.decode takes 2 arguments: input and output.

You certainly want to use `base64.b64decode(s)` which returns the decoded string.

Comment: both arguments are supposed to be files.